# Orchard CMS best options for list

Tags: orchardcms

I am new to orchard and am trying to find the best way to create a list of houses (name, address, pictures, prices and a few others). The houses are to be in two sections/ categories (Buy and Rent). These two options will appear on the menu. Then on clicking buy you get all houses flagged with that option and likewise for rent. I would also then like these displayed as images and brief description then on clicking more take you to a page with lots more details as mentioned above on the house. Then also like to have featured houses and latest houses buy/ rent widgets in the sidebar or similar.

There seems to be lots of ways to do this ie content types, projection, taxonomies, lists etc. But what is the best way in the case please. I dont want to go one way and then find i cant do it i would rather get some help here now and do it right.

Things i have read and watched to help:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uDqY14mDG_Y&feature=youtu.be

http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-lists

All help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You could create a content type called House with all the properties you described as fields.  Then create projections (filtered to only show Houses) to display your Buy and Rent listings.

Comment: Yeah this. It's simpler and makes more sense than taxonomies in this instance (taxonomy with only two options: Buy/Rent doesn't make sense), and "Lists" are deprecated in Orchard. They are replaced by Projections.

Comment: Thankyou both for your help. I will give that a go. I am bound to runinto a few problems so will post back here. Thanks

Comment: Actually I'd still use taxonomies here. That there are only two terms doesn't seem like a compelling argument against it. And projections and taxonomies are really not exclusive of one another.

Comment: Bertrand Le Roy can you please expand to give me an idea of how to achieve it (i still create a content type for my houses but do i not now use projections, if so how to i manage to get the different house views i mention above {latest houses, features houses, etc}). i have just watched your video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B3jhgTeiEtwAlso how can i have mulitple images against a content item then display them like ebay 1 big i with thumb nails, on clicking a thumb it replace the biig pic.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Also using taxonomies i would have houses > buy / rent. But how would i show 2 menu items buy and rent. with taxonomies i can only show the top level of houses. i would also like to associate each houses with a location ie wales > pembrokeshire etc. and allow side bar nav like buy > england > london/ birmigham or vice versa go birmingham > buy / rent