# Orchard CMS query on multiple taxonomies

Tags: orchardcms

I am useing taxonomies in orchard. i have two types of taxonomy 1: House > buy / rent. and 2. Location > spain / france/ uk. I have decided to use taxonomies based on my other post and orchard cms guru Bertrand Le Roy advice. [Orchard CMS best options for list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272473/orchard-cms-best-options-for-list/13272628#comment18118477_13272628)

**My example**

I have a house content type (tittle, body, 2 taxonomy fields {1: HouseType > buy, rent. and 2: Location > spain, france, uk} ) so a user will have to select 1: buy or rent. Then from the second taxonomy select the house location ie spain. I have 2 houses set up both use house type **buy** but 1 from location **spain** and 1 from location **uk**.

I know create a query and this is the problem: if i add a filter of taxonomy and choose buy i get both my houses **as expected**, if i set up the filter to have buy and spain (with only 1 filter but choose both from select box) i still get both houses **which is wrong** i would expect to only get 1. However if i have 2 seperate filters 1 buy and 2 spain then i get no results returned, **which is wrong**. Can some exlpain why this does not work and how to overcome it. I need to be able to say in the query get me, eg. all houses in spain that are of type buy and only got those houses.

Thanks

Comment: Can someone plese confirm if this is a bug or if i am doing something wrong. Thanks

Comment: issue has been raised on orchard.codeplex